# Alignment issue in the Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic section

Tags: bug, status-completed, flags, design

There is a minor alignment issue in the **Flagging > Closing > Off-Topic** section.

The radio button's margin-top is not matching with the text content, in remaining sections the alignment is set correctly.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Flagging Off-topic questions]

Steps to see the window:

- click on the **flag** link in any of the question, then
- click on the **Should be closed...** radio button, then
- click on the **off-topic because...** radio button

OS: Windows 8.1
Mozilla Firefox: 50.1.0
Google chrome: 51.0.2704.103 m
Zoom: 100%

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fixed now, see [Close dialog radios misaligned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356597/close-dialog-radios-misaligned/357208#357208) on meta.SO.

Comment: could this be a side effect of the fix? [Misalignment with radio buttons in add comment dialog in LQP queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301479/165773)

Comment: Probably. Looking, thanks.

Comment: folks also report very similar issue in [suggested edits review](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357231/839601)

Comment: Both fixed, thank you.