# Misalignment with radio buttons in add comment dialog in LQP queue

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, design, low-quality-posts

As you can see, the text is not on the same line as its radio button:

> [image]

This makes the entire dialog too big vertically and doesn't make sense from a UX perspective.

It was not like this before. (I could only find [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNdpw.png) really old screenshot, but you should get the point.)

(In case it's relevant, I'm on Mac using Chrome "Version 61.0.3163.100 (Official Build) (64-bit)".)

Comment: Same for me on AskUbuntu too. Firefox 55.03 and Win 7.

Comment: same error with FF 51 on vista (https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCAyN.png). this error was not there this morning. Was there a new build today?

Comment: @David I'm not sure if they are related, but [a small misalignment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356597/close-dialog-radios-misaligned) was fixed today

Comment: also reported at MSO: [LQP Delete reason radios misaligned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/357221/839601)

Answer (score 1):

As has been theorized, this was indeed a side effect of [this fix](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356597/close-dialog-radios-misaligned/357208#357208). We have a lot of these popups, and it turns out they're all slightly different.

I've fixed these so far:

- LQP deletion comment (the one you reported; also [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357221/lqp-delete-reason-radios-misaligned))
- [moderator flag decline reason](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357221/lqp-delete-reason-radios-misaligned#comment518225_357221)
- [suggested edit rejection](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357231/labels-miss-aligned-reject-reason-modal)
- bounty reason
- moderator message template
- community team message template

I think that's all, but please report any others you find.

Comment: CV dialog still broken https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301503/278094

Comment: @David In a different way though ;p working on that already, thanks.