# Misaligned options still in the Close Vote popup dialog

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, close-dialog

It seems the CV popup is still broken ([Misalignment with radio buttons in add comment dialog in LQP queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301479/278094), and [Close dialog radios misaligned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357208/3220986) for some history on these bugs.)
Any time there is a counter for number of votes already cast the layout is screwed up. I'm still using FireFox 51 on vista.

[image: broken CV dialog]

If it helps, getting rid of the `margin-top: -17px` in the `.action-list:not(.popup-condensed) .action-desc` selector fixes this issue, but then the spacing for all the others is wrong...

Comment: [because...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYOnP.jpg)

Comment: See also [on meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357243/text-overlap-in-vote-to-close-dialog)

Comment: This is fixed in the code already, I'll deploy it shortly (original report [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/357231/labels-misaligned-reject-reason-modal/357235?noredirect=1#comment518303_357235)).